# Switch for enable/disable vibration and sound with button

Tags: android, audio, vibration

With Android Studio. I have two buttons that when pressed emits vibration and sound. I put in the layout two switches on / off in order to enable / disable the vibration and the sound of the two buttons. I tried to set the code but when I start the app, it crashes and error.
Can someone help me?

This is code java:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.opzioni);

    final Switch onOffSwitchvibr = (Switch)  findViewById(R.id.switch2);
    onOffSwitchvibr.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton View, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                onOffSwitchvibr.isEnabled();

                // The toggle is enabled
            } else {
                onOffSwitchvibr.getTextOff();
                return;
                // The toggle is disabled
            }
        }


    });

}





}
```

And this is code xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:text="SETTINGS"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#999999"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="#B2B2B2"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/switch1"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"

    android:onClick="onSwitchClicked"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:switchTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
    android:background="#999999"/>
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/switch2"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textOn="ON"
    android:textOff="OFF"

    android:onClick="onSwitchClicked"
    android:switchTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without telling us what error you get. But a few things...

Check that your xml file is called the same as what you are setting the content view (opzioni.xml)

```
setContentView(R.layout.opzioni);
```

Also, in your xml, for both of your switches you have set up an interface call to a method:

```
android:onClick="onSwitchClicked"
```

which tells the button view object to call the following method in your activity when touched:

```
public void onSwitchClicked(View v)
```

But since you haven't defined it, you will get a error.

So either define that method in your activity or remove that line from your xml.